# Android Out Of Memory Exceptions

Tags: android, exception, memory

I have an application I am writing that is heavy with bitmaps. If you start the app, exit the app and come back into the app several times eventually you get a forced close because of an out of memory condition.

I know where the out of memory is happening and could do a try catch. The problem is that if I don't have the memory to run, what do I do? My app just doesn't work without the bitmaps, so I can't just not show them.

I have tried setting things to null when I get the onPause. I have tried doing finish in onPause. I did a lot of research an read many postings before writing this email and have tried the many things suggested.

The bottom line is that the memory I use just doesn't seem to be getting freed or something else is going on.

I tried using the adb shell cat /proc/meminfo command in between starts and stops and here is what I found:

MemTotal: 31348

Start app, everything working

MemTotal: 18180

Exit app

MemTotal: 20160

Start app, everything working

MemTotal: 12480

Exit app

MemTotal: 13740

Start app, everything working

MemTotal: 9600

Exit app

MemTotal: 10844

Start app, first memory exception, one of 5 bitmaps just doesn't show up, but no crash

MemTotal: 6224

Exit app

MemTotal: 7244

Start app, doesn't start, gets out of memory which causes an error that I catch, so exits

MemTotal: 7836

Start app, out of memory exception and Force Close, hit force close button

MemTotal: 31648

As you can see the memory is now finally released, but only after a force close.

It doesn't matter if I start and exit really fast or wait between each start and finish the same thing happens, so I can't just introduce a delay.

Is there a way to "force" a Force Close except not really show the message and not be an error condition? I thought that is what finish() was supposed to do, but it doesn't.

Thanks for any help or ideas I can try.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't actually setting everything to null that you need to. If you post some code showing all the data structures that keep references to your bitmaps, perhaps we could help. Also, look into using the allocation tracker (described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/track-memory-allocations.html)).

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with our app. Unfortunately there is no 'silver bullet' to solve all of memory issues. Here are a couple of things you can try:
i) Use soft reference/ weak reference for the bitmaps you use.
ii) Recycle bitmaps in your onPause and decode them again in your onResume. A cache of soft referenced bitmaps will help.
iii) Consider using RGB_565 instead of ARGB_8888 (which is now the default in Gingerbread).
iv) Make sure that there are no leaks or multiple instances of your activity/activities.

Hope this helps.